# Firebase database rules: How to prevent a certain child from being deleted (a.k.a NOT NULL)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to define a schema in firebase that will prevent certain child properties from being null (like the NOT NULL constraint in SQL).

The schema should look like this:

```
Property | allow null | type
---------+------------+--------
name     | false      | string
phone    | false      | string
alias    | true       | string
birthday | true       | number (timestamp)
```

In addition, only the user himself should be able to read and write his own contacts.

Currently the database has some dummy data in it:

```
{
  "contacts" : {
    "user1" : {
      "contact1" : {
        "alias" : "Bobby",
        "name" : "Bob",
        "phone" : "12312324"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The solution that I came up with looks like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "contacts": {
      "$user": {
        "$contact": {
          ".read": "auth.uid == $user",
          ".write": "auth.uid == $user && newData.hasChildren(['name', 'phone'])",
          "name": {
            ".validate": "newData.isString()"
          },
          "phone": {
            ".validate": "newData.isString()"
          },
          "alias": {
            ".validate": "newData.isString()"
          },
          "birthday": {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
          },
          "$other": {
            ".validate": "false"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that every time that I want to patch a certain value (for example the alias), I have to provide the not null properties (that aren't changed) due to the `newData.hasChildren(['name', 'phone']` rule.

Although I have access to the entire object in my app, this is an annoying inconvenience.

Is there a better approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Firebase has no schema so it's usually best to not force a SQL concept on a NoSQL database - think and design your structure for NoSQL! For example; trying to prevent certain child properties from being null. Why? What would happen if the data was absent? If you want to ensure it has data, what data? Firebase doesn't allow empty strings so that means you need to have something as a child value placeholder. In the case of NoSQL, the lack of a child node is usually better than a placeholder. Handle those cases in code;  if !phoneChildNode.exists() then let phoneVar = "no phone provided"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem with this approach is that every time that I want to patch a certain value (for example the alias), I have to provide the not null properties (that aren't changed) due to the `newData.hasChildren(['name', 'phone']` rule.

You seem to misunderstand the meaning of `newData` in rules. From the [reference documentation of `newData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#newdata):

> A `RuleDataSnapshot` corresponding to the data that will result **if the write is allowed**.

So if you write just a single property to a location that already contains all of the properties, the `newData` variable will contain all properties: the existing value for unspecified ones, and the new value for the property you're writing.

Comment: Then why does the simulator shows that the write is denied (using the dummy data)?  [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/kh6td0u.png)

Comment: Because you're simulating a `set()` operation on the entire user. That would replace the entire contact, including the `name` and `phone` properties. To simulate an `update()`, write `"value"` to `contacts/user1/contact1/alias`.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up a lot of confusion and frustration.